# Java what layout manager to use to divide window into two areas

Tags: java, jpanel, layout-manager

well I need a few tips on which layout managers to use to divide a frame into two regions, let's say on the left side of the frame a drawing jpanel would be inserted and on the right side of the frame I would create buttons and other stuff to control it. So what layout manager should I use and how should it look? Because last time I needed something like that I tried using box layout and then borderlayout, but I guess I didn't know how to use it properly cause the result wasn't good.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a JSplitPane is what you want and need.

It does exactly what you want: split a frame in 2 independent areas in which you can do whatever you want.

Since this is your only component, I think a FlowLayout for the parent frame would suffice.

For more details see here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html

Answer (score 2):

I would go with a BorderLayout.  Put your navigation stuff at `orderLayout.EAST` or `BorderLayout.WEST` (for left and right respectively), seems like you want `WEST`.  Then either specify a Border.CENTER for your content or don't specify one.

```
JPanel parent = new JPanel();
parent.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
JPanel navigation = createNavigation();
JPanel content = createContent();

parent.add(navigation, BorderLayout.WEST);
parent.add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);  // or parent.add(content);
```

@Razvan has a good point, especially if you want that divider for the user to have manual control over the widths of the two layouts.  Border layout will fit the side panel to the minimum size the components need and put all the extra space in the `CENTER` area.

More details here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html